# How can I avoid growing my hashmaps to 2 keys until I try to add a second key?

Tags: java, hashmap, out-of-memory

I have a situation where I have tons of hashmaps (millions and millions) in my server, and 95% of them have literally only one key, ever.

The server runs out of memory; which probably may have something to do with the fact that initial HashMap default size is 16, so for every HashMap object I'm wasting a ton of memory.

Short of re-designing the server with a new data structure that flexibly stores the data as 1 element OR an entire hashmap (which I'd prefer avoiding), I'm trying to first optimize this by changing the initial size to 1:

```
Map<String, Type2> myMiniMap = new HashMap<>(1);
```

However, my concern is that due to default load factor of 0.75 in HashMaps, this would immediately get increased to 2 the moment I add the first key to the map (since `1*0.75 < 1`, which is how I understand hash sizing logic in Java)

Assuming my understanding above is correct (that by default, Java will create a space for 2 keys as soon as I add the first key to the hash), **is there a way to prevent this from happening till I actually try to insert the second key**?

E.g., should I set loadFactor to zero or one?

Comment: *Why* do you have all these maps? It sounds like the data structure really does need to be resolved.

Comment: You need to set capacity=2, or you can set capacity=1 and loadFactor>1.0.    The difference between the two choices won't make a significant difference to your memory consumption, though -- there's a lot more space than that wasted inside the HashMap

Comment: @chrylis - because ~5% of the data does have more than 1 key. I'm not sure if creating custom class to do something like this would lead to even worse memory use, to be honest, as well as being harder to understand - so I'd prefer to explore solutions that are less complex from code readability standpoint first. However, if you think there's a memory-optimal class to fix this issue; please let me know and I'll ask as a separate question so you can post that as an answer/

Comment: @MattTimmermans - is there a good guide on where the memory is wasted?

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java

Comment: Use `Collections.singletonMap(key, value)`

Comment: @FranMontero - how would this work with 5% of the cases where I have >1 key?

Comment: No, I mean why are you using maps in the first place?

Comment: @chrylis - because in those 5% of cases of multiple keys; I need to answer  "does this key set have a specific key" - preferably in O(1) speed; which rules out storing this whole shebang in a list.

Comment: if(more than one key) use `Collections.singletonMap(key, value)`
else use `new HashMap(number_of_keys)` this way you will have just the required elements in all yous hashmaps

Comment: @FranMontero - close enough. I had to hand-implement my own singletonMap (not a big deal) as the Collections one is broken (it doesn't support "empty" maps semantically); but this did work as desired.

Answer (score 1):

If they're truly only ever going to be singletons, why not use `Collections.singletonMap` to create them? The downside of this is that the map that is created is immutable.

Alternatively, you could create your own class implementing `Map` that will store a key and value in class fields and then, if an attempt is made to add a second key value, it will switch to using a `HashMap` as its default backing store. It would be more tedious than difficult to accomplish.

Comment: What would be the memory performance of such a class (that switches to HashMap) compared to simple HashMap with default size of 1?